# emacs keeps popping up "buffer menu" when I don't want it

Tags: window, emacs

Ubuntu 14.04, HP ZBook
GNU Emacs 23.1.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.18.9)

When I'm typing into a buffer, or just moving the cursor with ^N,^P, etc, often emacs pops up a "buffer menu" window(this is a separate X window).  Why does this happen and how can I stop it?

Comment: Sorry, I've been using emacs since 1975... it's in my firmware now...

Comment: My apologies. I've lost count of the editors I've used since 1975. ;-) Unfortunately I don't use emacs. Hopefully someone else in the community can chime in on this one.. You might find this useful though: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Several-Buffers.html

Comment: Or this: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html#Keyboard-Macros

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem. You can figure out what keystrokes just took place (after dismissing the window) with "C-h l". In my case it was C-mouse-1 because on my laptop the mouse pad is right where I like to rest my palms when typing. Even though I use a regular mouse, it still processes the mouse pad. You can disable it by using global-set-key to make C-mouse-1 undefined (simply provide no new setting).

Answer (score 1):

Quick workaround: Before typing in an emacs window that displays this behavior, move the mouse cursor to a region of the window where Ctrl-mouse-1 has no effect (eg. the top "window handle" region. Now you can type without fear of having the buffer menu popup on you every so often. (I hope).

The permanent fix is somewhere outside of emacs, either in the window manager, or X11 configuration.  By default, emacs has variable: *make-pointer-invisible* set to *t* (true) which will cause proper behavior when typing. Something external to emacs is causing emacs to only sometimes hide the pointer when typing.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Len pointed me in the right direction but it still took me quite a while to figure out how to implement it, this command worked for me to stop my touchpad triggering the buffer menu:

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-<down-mouse-1>"))
```

Put it in your init file and you won't have the issue with your touchpad anymore.